# std::vector<std::string> and push_back

Tags: c++

I operate a bunch of web sites so I was trying to make my list using

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>
//.......................................
#include "stdafx.h"

 HWND vbrowser;
 std::vector<std::string> sites;
 sites.push_back("https://hardcoregames.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin/");


 wchar_t *convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(const char* charArray)
 {
//  wchar_t* wString = new wchar_t[4096];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, charArray, -1, wString, 4096);
    return wString;
 }

 int main()
{
     CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
    ShellExecute(vbrowser, convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR("open"), convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(url.c_str()), NULL, NULL, NULL);
     return 0;
 }
```

so I was thinking, I can hard code the sites, I only operate a few

but when I was attempting to use:

```
 sites.push_back ("https://hardcoregames.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin/");
```

vc 2017 did not like that, says there is no storage class or type specifier, then it suggested I use a semicolon;

my project is to open the admin page, and wait a few bit before moving on to the next site

vc 2017 community edition

I was wanting to be able to bring up the admins screens in wordpress

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);
ShellExecute(vbrowser, convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR("open"), convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(url.c_str()), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - half the code you've included is irrelevant to your immediate problem. Show us the code that causes the error.

Comment: HWND vbrowser;
std::vector<std::string> sites;
sites.push_back("https://hardcoregames.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin/")

Comment: Your edited code doesn't have a semicolon at the end of the `push_back` line. Is that intentional or a typo? If it's a typo, then the error must be elsewhere. Have you included the `string` and `vector` header files?

Comment: yes I have string and vector in my stdafx.h along with a few others

Comment: Include some more context around your code - is this being run in a function?

Comment: curiously if I use = {site, site2, site3, site4} it works fine, the code has all the semicolons, missed one when i cut and pasted

Comment: Unrelated: In Visual Studio,  `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the first include. Everything above will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a member function outside of a function - that's illegal in C++ except when initializing a variable.
Specifically, this line:

```
sites.push_back("https://hardcoregames.azurewebsites.net/wp-admin/");
```

has to be inside a function somewhere.

You can set the `vector`'s values at compile time using:

```
std::vector<std::string> sites = { site1, site2 };
```

as you noted in a comment as that's a variable initialisation.

Alternatively, you can move your `push_back` statement into the `main` function and just run it at program startup - you could even go the whole hog and get rid of the global variables in favour of local ones (which would be a very good design choice...)

Comment: look at the example here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back

Comment: I just did - and they use `push_back` **inside another function**.

Comment: Pedantic: "that's illegal in C++" it's legal in an initialization. Can't think of a good way to call `push_pack` in an initialization, though.

Comment: @user4581301 I appreciate the pedantry - if there's a more correct way of phrasing the above, please let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: How does " that's illegal in C++ except when initializing a variable" sound?

Comment: any way with shellexecute to get the hwnd of the spawned browser? the idea is to use sleep for a while to read the screen before moving on

Comment: @VeganFanatic Post a new question for that, don't hijack this one. If the problem you stated in this question is fixed, consider [accepting an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).